# Determine clicked row in DevExpress GridControl

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

I have a DevExpress GridControl:

```
<dxg:GridControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyData}" MouseDoubleClick="GridControl_MouseDoubleClick" />
```

In the event handler I can determine the focused row nicely by calling `GetFocusedRow()`. However, the handler gets also called when the scroll bar gets clicked twice in quick succession.

How can I determine if the user actually double-clicked a row? Or can I easily attach an event handler to the rows without much restyling?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is all you need:

```
TableViewHitInfo hi = ((TableView)gridControl.View).CalcHitInfo(e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject);

if (hi.InRow)
{
    //Do work...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here -> [Wpf datagrid row double click](http://dotnet-experience.blogspot.de/2011/01/wpf-datagrid-row-double-click.html) you can find a nice article for that topic.